# Truncating a string after x amount of charcters

Tags: php, string

I have a string that that is an unknown length and characters.

I'd like to be able to truncate the string after x amount of characters.

For example from:

```
$string = "Hello# m#y name # is Ala#n Colem#n"
$character = "#"
$x = 4
```

I'd like to return:

```
"Hello# m#y name # is Ala#"
```

Hope I'm not over complicating things here!

Many thanks

Comment: do you mean, in the example in the question, everything up to the 4th occurrence of "#" ?

Comment: That's correct, I'm thinking there must be a php function which means I won't have to loop through?

Comment: A loop with `strtok` & build a new string seems most efficient. Of course, you can go the `$arr = explode($character,$string,$x+1);$newstring = implode('#',array_slice($arr,0,4))`  route.

Comment: And why do you hate loops?

Answer (score 4):

```
function posncut( $input, $delim, $x ) {
    $p = 0;
    for( $i = 0; $i < $x; ++ $i ) {
        $p = strpos( $input, $delim, $p );
        if( $p === false ) {
            return "";
        }
        ++ $p;
    }
    return substr( $input, 0, $p );
}
echo posncut( $string, $character, $x );
```

It finds each delimiter in turn (`strpos`) and stops after the one you're looking for. If it runs out of text first (`strpos` returns `false`), it gives an empty string.

Update: here's a benchmark I made which compares this method against explode: http://codepad.org/rxTt79PC. Seems that `explode` (when used with `array_pop` instead of `array_slice`) is faster.

Comment: not "my" - thanks for the benchmark +1 just for providing it (should reference it in your answer). It's hard to judge code by appearances, and doing so often erroneous =)

Comment: added it, and cleaned up the comment thread above, because it looked like I was talking to myself :P

Answer (score 4):

I'd suggest `explode`-ing the string on `#`, then getting the 1st 4 elements in that array.

```
$string = "Hello# m#y name # is Ala#n Colem#n";
$character = "#";
$x = 4;

$split = explode($character, $string);
$split = array_slice($split, 0, $x);

$newString = implode($character, $split).'#';
```

Answer (score 1):

Something along these lines:

```
$str_length =  strlen($string)
$character = "#"
$target_count = 4

$count = 0;
for ($i = 0 ; $i<$str_length ; $i++){
    if ($string[$i] == $character) {
        $count++
        if($count == $target_count) break;
    }

}

$result = sub_str($string,0,$i)
```